# ООП C# методы задача это в заголовке

Tags: c#, методы

//Объясните пожалуйста, почему метод не выводится.Вижуал студио ругается, сообщая что имя FirstOption(my list) ,не существует в контексте

```
    public struct Diary
    {
    //создание номера
    public int Number { get; set; }
    //создание Имя
    public string Name { get;set; }
    //создание Даты и Время
    public DateTime ParsedDate {get;set;}
    //создание Место
    public string Place { get;set; }
    //создание Действие
    public string Action { get;set; }
    }
    public struct WorkWithData
    {
    //Метод добавления
    public static List<Diary> FirstOption(List<Diary> myList)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(" - цифра нажатая вами (Добавление)");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Номер");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Имя");
        string m = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Дату и Время");
        DateTime l = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Место");
        string p = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Действие");
        string f = Console.ReadLine();

        myList.Add(new Diary() { Number = n, Name = m, ParsedDate = l, Place = p, Action = f });

        foreach (Diary d in myList)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", d.Number, d.Name, d.ParsedDate, d.Place, d.Action);

        }
        return myList;
    }       
    }
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Diary> myList = new List<Diary>();

        myList = FirstOption(myList);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Где у вас находится `FirstOption`? Внутри чего?

Comment: `myList = FirstOption(myList);` ==> `myList = Diary.FirstOption(myList);`

Comment: Не получается (

Answer (score 0):

Метод `FirstOption` объявлен в структуре `Diary`, а попытка вызова идет в классе `Program`.

Для решения нужно либо перенести объявление этого метода в класс `Program`,
либо обращаться к нему указывая сначала тип, в котором он объявлен: `myList = Diary.FirstOption(myList)`